# Function name not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

I have a pice of code which looks like this

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


def main():
    print("hello")
```

However, when I try to run this code I get the error

> NameError: name 'main' is not defined

Have I not defined the name in the first line of the function "def main()"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define main before call it

```
def main():
    print("hello")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 5):

> Have I not defined the name in the first line of the function "def main()"?

Yes, but Python hasn't executed that definition yet. Put the function definition before the call.

Comment: That's a good way to put it.  Understanding that `def` is *executed* is an important part of learning Python.  Once you grok that, many things which otherwise would seem strange (why mutable default arguments act the way they do, how the scoping in nested functions works) make sense all of a sudden.